# pg_basebackup and multiple tablespaces

Tags: postgresql, backup, tablespaces

I have the following case:

- the master database has an additional tablespace
- I'm trying to replicate the master with the `pg_basebackup` tool
- the directory / partition layout on the slave is the same as on the master

What parameters should I use to set up replication safely? Do I need to map tablespace with **-T** parameter or is it only required if I am doing `pg_basebackup` on the master? `pg_basebackup` is generaly safe? Data not be deleted from the master?

My command is:

```
db_slave# pg_basebackup -h db_master -p 5433 -U replication -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -P -Xs -Fp -R
```

But I get:

```
pg_basebackup: error: directory "/home/db" exists but is not empty
pg_basebackup: removing data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/12/main"
```

Tablespace is store in */home/db*. Thanks a lot for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pg_basebackup` without `-T`, it assumes that the tablespace directories are in the same location as on the primary database machine. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html) states:

> As with the main target directory, `newdir` need not exist already, but if
> it does exist it must be empty.

If you want to backup the tablespaces to a different location, use the `-T` option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I make a backup using pg_basebackup without changing the tablespace location (without -T parameter), they will be placed on the slave server in the same location as on the master server. I understand that they will not be touched on the master?

Comment: Yes, they will be placed in the same place on the standby. They will certainly be touched on the primary - but only read.